# From Summation Notation to Matrix Representation

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

I have trouble understanding something from the Scahum's Linear algebra series on bilinear forms:

\begin{array}{l}{\text { Let } f \text { be a bilinear form on } V \text { and let } S=\left\{u_{1}, \ldots, u_{n}\right\} \text { be a basis of } V . \text { Suppose } u, v \in V \text { and }} \\ {u=a_{1} u_{1}+\cdots+a_{n} u_{n} \quad \text { and } \quad v=b_{1} u_{1}+\cdots+b_{n} u_{n}} \\ {\text { Then }} \\ {\qquad f(u, v)=f\left(a_{1} u_{1}+\cdots+a_{n} u_{n}, \quad b_{1} u_{1}+\cdots+b_{n} u_{n}\right)=\sum_{i, j} a_{i} b_{j} f\left(u_{i}, u_{j}\right)}\end{array}

It then continues and gives:

$$f(u, v)=\sum_{i, j} a_{i} b_{j} f\left(u_{i}, u_{j}\right)=[u]_{S}^{T} A[v]_{S}$$

Which is what I do not understand. How does one go from expressing something in summation notation to a matrix representation? I've verified that it works but just can't get my head around why.

Comment: Here $(i,j)$-th entry of $A$ is $f(u_i,u_j)$.

Comment: If you verified the computations, then you should see clearly why it works because it is written in front of you. What are you exactly asking for? The intuition behind converting sums to matrix products?

Comment: @EnderWiggins Yes, the intuition behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $A = (a_{ij})$ an $n\times n$ matrix defined by $a_{ij} = f(u_{i},u_{j})$. Besides, you can write $$v = \begin{pmatrix} b_{1} \\ \vdots \\ b_{n} \end{pmatrix} \quad u = \begin{pmatrix} a_{1} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n} \end{pmatrix} $$
What is the result of the product $u^{T}A v$?